# Flip integer from 1 to 0 or the other way around. Bitwise-operations

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I have integer variable `a` and another integer variable `p`. `p` is position. I want to flip the integer bite at position `p`. If the bit which is at position `p`of the variable `a` is `0` I want to change it to `1` and if the bit which is at position `p`of the variable `a` is `1` I want to change it to `0`. How can I do it? I am writing it in Java but explanation in any language is fine.

Comment: See "toggle". That was a C++ question but that doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: Thanks @harold it worked!